Why onended event of MediaTrack is not fired?
I need to add mp3-file audio track to RtcPeerConnection.
This work fine, local computer loads mp3-file, converts it to blob,
creates Audio() object, a stream, sends it track[0], a peer listens it.
Also I need to capture onendedevent of the added track, but it is not fired.
However, the same event of the created Audio is captured normally - see comments in my code.
The question is - why newAudio onended is captured and newTrackToAdd's is not ?
My code is:
try {
    // blobURL - is the data of loaded mp3-file
    let newAudio = new Audio(blobURL);                   // CREATED OK
    newAudio.autoplay = true;

    newAudio.addEventListener("play", (e) => {
        DisplayEventMessage("play: ", "NewAudio");       // THIS EVENT IS FIRED - OK

    });

    
    newAudio.addEventListener("ended", (e) => {
        DisplayEventMessage("ended: ", "NewAudio");       // THIS EVENT IS FIRED - OK
        // IT IS FIRED !!!
    });
    
    // create a stream to pass mp3-file 
    const ctxAudio = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const streamDest = ctxAudio.createMediaStreamDestination();
    const streamSource = ctxAudio.createMediaElementSource(newAudio);
    streamSource.connect(streamDest);
    const newStream = streamDest.stream;


    console.log("--- newStream ---");
    console.log(newStream);

    const addAudioTrack = true;


        allTracks = newStream.getAudioTracks();
………

            // get a track to add
            let newTrackToAdd = allTracks[0];

            newTrackToAdd.onended = function(e) {

                alert("onended!");                             // IT IS NOT FIRED !!! WHY ???
                DisplayEventMessage("onended: ", "newTrackToAdd");
            };

            // add the track to webrtc - it works, a peer listens the mp3-file
            rtc_addExtraTrack(curWebRtc, newTrackToAdd);


